# Asyncore Poll in Windows - Python

Tags: python, sockets, asyncore

I need to use [`poll()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/select.html#select.poll) instead of [`select()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/select.html#select.select) in my `AsyncServer`, due to some "*bad file name descriptor*" errors, during high load to the server code.

This is what I came up in Linux (which satisfy my needs):

```
    asyncore.loop(use_poll=True)
```

In Windows environment, there is no `poll()`, as far as I know, instead [`WSAPoll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsapoll) is exist, but is not supported by Python.

Is there any way to use `poll()` in Windows? Or how to solve this problem in windows environment.

Comment: Consider using Twisted for high-load applications.  It is actively maintained, unlikely asyncore, has many more features, and performs better.  It also supports I/O Completion Ports on Windows, which is a much better system than either select or poll.

Comment: Used Twisted. It rocks, thanks for advice.